# Is libssh2 has a swift wrapper?

Tags: swift, libssh2

I want to build a SFTP app for ios,and there are some object-c ssh libs.But my project is write in swift,so I want to know is there ssh lib write in swift.

Comment: Duuude, use [Google](https://www.google.ch/search?q=libssh2+swift&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari) before asking a question. And Swift can use any framework in Objective-C..

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I know swift could use Object-c framework.I just want to know if there is a swift framework,I use google search it,but no result.

Comment: Why do you NEED a Swift framework?

Comment: I found that you are right,object-c framework works well from swift.